# Rotation breaks in CSS animation when height/width is defined in keyframes

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, css-transforms

I've got an element which i'm trying to animate in. I want to do the animation in two steps, first scale and rotate a square in, and then widen the square. I start off by `transform: scale(.1) rotateX(360deg);` and animate to `transform: none`, which works well. But as soon as i (in any step) declare a height/width in the keyframes, the rotation stops working. It will still scale as it should, and the height/width properties are applied, but the rotation is skipped entirely.

Here is a Codepen to demonstrate the issue:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/abDCK

As you see, there's no rotation going on in there, it just simply scales in. Now, scroll down in the CSS and comment out the height/width properties, and you'll see that the rotation now suddenly works.

I've tried different combinations of having/not having height/width declared in the normal selector (not in the keyframe), i've also tried putting the height/width declarations in different steps in the keyframes. No success.

I get the same result in both Firefox in Chrome. Is this the intended behaviour? If so, why? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

Something to do with the transforms in the keyframes not being balanced?. You need to add translateX(0deg) to either the 40% keyframe, of 100% keyframe, depending on where you want it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lJKkD

I'd sure love it if somebody could explain the reason - but this is the "solution"

Comment: Yup, that did it! `transform: none` on 40% was enough though, putting it on 100% did nothing. I too would like to know the reason behind this.

Comment: @Adam - It would be best if you included all applicable code for your solution directly in the answer.